# It it possible to configure Compare to use the Merge tool instead of the Diff tool?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I often need to compare the current version of a file with some previous one, and copy bits from one to the other. I can get close with TFS Compare:

[image]

except that by default, Compare uses the Diff tool, which only lets me view the diffs, but not copy from one file to another:

[image]

TFS comes with a Merge tool, which does let me copy, so is there a way to use this for comparing, or some other way to invoke the Merge tool, specifying the current file and a previous version? (I know that I could set this up with command line arguments, but then I'd have to do a lot of manual work to pass the current filename, get the previous version from TFS into a temp file and pass that filename. I'm looking for something that's integrated into Solution Explorer, and works like Compare, so it's just a couple of clicks away.)

Comment: The diff tool should have the local side editable (if one of the sides *is* local.)  Can you show a screenshot of the choices you've made on the "compare" dialog?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try, but when I do I will be sure to come back and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I love using WinMerge for both the operations. You can find instructions on how to do it here: http://blog.degree.no/2013/12/using-winmerge-as-the-default-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-2012/